# How to substitude / delete multiple lines inplace?

Tags: bash, perl, unix, awk, sed

I want to use `find . -name *.php -exec COMMAND {} \;` on a debian based system to delete pattern like this:

```
<?php
#bVj7Gt#
line1
...
lineX
#/bVj7Gt#
?>
```

The line after `<?php` = hash + six alphanumeric + hash

The line before `?>` = hash + slash + six alphanumeric + hash

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write a solution.
Given the tags you've included, I'd expect to see bash, perl, awk and sed code in your question. Review [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: I tried it with following regex `<\?php\n\#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\#.*\?>` in sed and awk, but don't get a working solution.

Comment: `sed` and `awk` only work line-by-line, so a multiline regex will not work easily there. You can try Perl: `perl -0777 -i.bak -wple 's/<\?php\s+#(\w{6})#.*?\s+#\1#\s+\?>//msg'`

Comment: Is there any chance of "?>" appearing in the inner lines?

Comment: @Corion no, awk works record by record, not line by line, and so awk can be used with multi-line regexps. sTealth please [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input (not just the block you want removed from that input) and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not be what you're looking for (since you didn't provide sample input/output we could test against) using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ cat file
foo
<?php
#bVj7Gt#
line1
...
lineX
#/bVj7Gt#
?>
bar

$ awk -v RS='<[?]php\n#[[:alnum:]]{6}#.*#/[[:alnum:]]{6}#\n[?]>\n' -v ORS= '1' file
foo
bar
```

Make it `awk -i inplace -v RS=...` if you want to do "inplace" editing.

Comment: It worked for me with `perl -0777 -i.bak -wple 's/<\?php\r\n\#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\#.*\?>//msg' file` many thanks to your help Ed and Corion.

Comment: I also tried it with awk now and it works with `awk -v RS='<[?]php\r\n#[[:alnum:]]{6}#.*#/[[:alnum:]]{6}#\r\n[?]>' -v ORS= '1' file` thank you Ed